# Specturm 3b in a link

Tags: model-theory

Can someone help with #3b in this link:

http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math502f09/ps3.pdf

I am trying to practice idea of spectrum, but cannot quite understand whatt they are asking for.

Thanks

Comment: It would be better to state the problem here (with proper attribution) rather than only citing a reference to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the definition of "spectrum" at the beginning of Problem 3, they are asking you to prove that the sentence $\phi$ in 3b (the conjunction of the four displayed sentences) has a model of size $n$ (a natural number) if and only if $n>3$ and $n$ is not prime.  If you don't "see" it easily, I suggest trying to build models of sizes $4$, $5$, and $6$ (i.e., take sets of those three sizes and try to interpret $P$, $Q$, and $f$ in them so as to make the four displayed sentences true). Once you see why you can succeed for $4$ and $6$ but not for $5$, the general situation should become clear.  (It might also be useful to think first about the last two of the four displayed sentences; although they're longer and more complicated than the first two, they incorporate the crucial idea.)

Comment: can you add your answer to the problem? I thought about it but dont see it well enough

Comment: The last two sentences will be true in a structure iff $f$ is a bijection from $P\times Q$ to the whole universe of the model.  (I'm writing $f$, $P$, $Q$ for short, where I really mean their interpretations in the model.)  So it provides a factorization of the cardinality of the universe as $|P|\cdot|Q|$. The first two sentences say that both factors are $\geq2$, so this factorization forces the size of the universe to be composite.  Conversely, given a set of composite size, you can choose subsets $P$ and $Q$ of the sizes in a factorization, and then choose a suitable bijection $f$.